# Specific hide delay of the classic gnome panel

Tags: 12.04, panel, gnome-classic

Is there an option in the gconf-editor or somewhere else where I can adjust the time of the hide delay of the panel in a classic-gnome session?

I found [this](http://justinstories.wordpress.com/2010/12/29/how-to-get-the-wingpanel-in-ubuntu-with-the-current-gnome-panel/) for GNOME2 but doesn't work with 12.04 classic panels

Answer (score 2):

The `hide-delay` key in `dconf-editor` under the entries under `/org/gnome/gnome-panel/layout/toplevels/` items in the tree, looks like what you're looking for.

Comment: The dconf-editor dos not save my configuration. So it dosnt work

Comment: I don't find anything working in the dconf-editor

Comment: It works for me in 12.04, but with a max value of 10000.